# Launch a terminal on startup on a specific workspace

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot, terminal, xubuntu

**Problem:**
At startup launch a xfce4-terminal at  workspace *x* with size and location *y*. Must use `.desktop` files

**Work done:**

```
17:34:13 - ~ - martin$ cd ~/.config/autostart/
17:34:19 - ~/.config/autostart - martin$ ls -l terminal_left_big.desktop 
-rw-rw-r-- 1 martin martin 115 май  7 17:30 terminal_left_big.desktop
17:36:33 - ~/.config/autostart - martin$ vim terminal_left_big.desktop


  1 [Desktop Entry]
  2 Type=Application
  3 Name=left_big
  4 Exec=xfce4-terminal --geometry 94x51+0+0 --title left_big
  5 Terminal=true
```

This is working properly. At startup a terminal with a specific size is being opened.

In a new terminal this works properly(a new terminal is being opened at a specific workspace):

```
17:39:02 - ~ - martin$ xfce4-terminal --geometry 94x51+0+0 --title 
asd; wmctrl -r asd -t 1
```

I tried it on my `.desktop` file:

```
 1 [Desktop Entry]
  2 Type=Application
  3 Name=left_big
  4 Exec=xfce4-terminal --geometry 94x51+0+0 --title asd; wmctrl -r asd -t 1
  5 Terminal=true
```

After reboot, after the login the loading of the desktop was longer then usual, a default terminal(with --title=Terminal and default geometry) opened for a second, then it got closed and after that the desktop icons loaded, my terminal was not loaded.

**Question:**

How do I open a startup terminal on a specific desktop?

Comment: 5 Terminal=false

Comment: Doesn't work eitherway